# Results Analysis in OMNET++

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am using Veins framework with OMNET++ to simulate a highway scenario.

I am using `cOutVector` to collect the results from my experiments.

I have more than 1000 nodes (vehicles), and the `cOutVector` collects results  individually for each module (node). However, I need to collect the overall results.

For example, How many beacons were received by all nodes? Is there anyway of collecting such results?

Answer (score 8):

In OMNeT++ the output results can be saved in two different types, and thus, file formats:

1. Scalars (`*.sca`) - contain summary data (mean, sum, count, max, min) for the whole simulation run
2. Vectors (`*.vec`) - contain fine-grained data (in form of time series) for each second of the simulation run

The output file formats are tightly coupled with the `statistic` mechanisms of OMNeT++. The statistics allow you to store different *result recording modes*, such as: count, sum, mean, vector.

In your case you would need to look at the `sum` for each of your nodes.

```
@statistic[foo](record=count,mean,vector);
```

---

These OMNeT++ mechanism seem complicated in the beginning, but they are rather easy once you wrap your head around. Also, they are very powerful giving insights to many aspects of your simulations.

- To understand the difference between scalars and vectors read [this](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec569).
- To understand results recording using signals read [this](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec401).
- For a concrete example of how to use the signals and record a specific statistic & metric, check my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30831800/4786271).

---

Unfortunately, it is impossible to provide a "ready-to-use" solution for your case without knowing your code.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, How many beacons were received by all nodes? Is there
>   anyway of collecting such results?

You can create a static variable and everytime a node receive one beacon you increase the value of this variable.

For example:
(on app_name.h)

`static int beaconCount; // in protected`

`int app_name::beaconCount = 0; // in the and of app_name.h, before #endif.`

(on app_name.cc)

```
void app_name::onBeacon(WaveShortMessage* wsm) {
    app_name::beaconCount++; // received one beacon
}
```

After this you can print the `beaconCount` in the function finish() or save in save file.

```
void app_name:: finish(){
  if(strcmp(findHost()->getFullName(), "car[0]") == 0){ // For only the car[0] print the final value
     cout << "Count of beacons received by all node:" << beaconCount << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do you mean you want to collect aggregate stats of all nodes?

If so then I suggest you to use R, which provides more functionalities and customization. Though, you'll need time to learn the basic operation.
There is tutorial in the omnetpp-resultfile Github page.