# Getting statistical data from OMnet++ simulations

Tags: omnet++, lte

I am using ***simulte*** library on OMNeT++ to simulate streaming video from a server to a user equipment(mobile phones) through eNodes. The simulation works fine, but the only problem is how can I get the statistics, for example, latency or throughput. If you can please help me with this since I'm on a tight schedule.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Results Analysis in OMNET++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368620/results-analysis-in-omnet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368620/results-analysis-in-omnet/31369454#31369454

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818192/calculating-end-to-end-delay-for-simpleserverapp-in-veins-lte/30831800#30831800

Comment: Thanks! Do you know another software for simulating LTE networks on Application Layer (high-level) because I find that OMNET++ is much close to the physical layer.

Comment: there might be some, but OMNeT++ is the one I am most familiar with... Whether OMNeT++ is close to the physical layer or not depends on how you configure your modules and what you want to investigate in detail. There are many examples where one can play around with the application layer and not care at all about the PHY

Comment: Can you guide me to simulation of Mobile Edge Computing platform?