# How to analyse path-loss in omnet++ for veins example?

Tags: omnet++, veins

How can i analyse the path-loss in veins, during the communication between two nodes. I looked through the analogue modules files and found that simple path-loss module is used but i don't know how this module could be used to accumulate the path-loss results. Do i have to add separate statistics to extract the path-loss results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path-loss is a communication phenomena. If you want to analyze it your have to look at metrics which quantify its effect.

As an analogy, if someone calls your name from distance you might not hear because the *signal power* (amplitude of the voice) has been attenuated due to the distance.

For example, you can look at `recvPower` in `decider80211p`, or higher level statistics which are recorded in `mac1609_4`

For more information about the path loss in Veins, you can consider this Q&A: [Maximum transmission range vs maximum interference distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712578/maximum-transmission-range-vs-maximum-interference-distance)

Comment: thank you so much for the answer but can you please tell how can i extract the higher level statistics that are recorded in mac1609_4?

Comment: regarding statistics you can refer to my answers here: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368620/results-analysis-in-omnet/31369454#31369454 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818192/calculating-end-to-end-delay-for-simpleserverapp-in-veins-lte/30831800#30831800 ... If you find the answers helpful mark them as accepted and possibly upvote so they can guide people with similar issues