# Where exactly should I place the code for statistics in veins-lte example

Tags: c++, networking, simulation, omnet++

I would like to collect new statistics in my  veins-lte scenario.

My enquire is where exactly should I place the code below in order to have for instance end-to-end delay.

Which .NED file, which .h file and which .cc file

1) I should add inside

NED:
    @signaldelay;

```
@statistic[delay](title="delay"; source="delay"; record=mean, sum, stats, vector);
```

It is not clear to me which .NED file

my .ned file or inside Mac1609_4.ned from the

veins-lte/veins/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p

2) add in  .h simsignal_t delaySignal;

again in which .h file 
 HeterogeneoustoLTE.h OR Mac1609_4.h or other

3) add delaySignal = registerSignal("delay");

to .cc (again which .cc file Mac1609_4.cc or HeterogeneoustoLTE.cc)

4) add  .cc emit(delaySignal, delay);

to .cc (again which .cc file Mac1609_4.cc or HeterogeneoustoLTE.cc)

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818192/calculating-end-to-end-delay-for-simpleserverapp-in-veins-lte