# how to measure throughput and end to end delay in veins-lte

Tags: omnet++

Hi does anybody know how to utilize a thruputMeter in standardHost.ned of VEINS-LTE in order to measure udp throughput of SimpleServerApp.

And how to emit delay in.cc ExampleDecisionMaker.cc in order to measure end to end delay cause I get 0 results.

Thnx 
Garry

Comment: You can collect the size of a message in the function `handleMessageWhenUp()` in the `SimpleServerApp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating end-to-end delay for SimpleServerApp in Veins-LTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818192/calculating-end-to-end-delay-for-simpleserverapp-in-veins-lte)